# How to filter duplicates with swapping column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pd.Dataframe that looks like this:

```
   a_p1  a_x1  a_x2  b_p1  b_x1  b_x2
1   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  -1.0   0.0
2   1.0  -1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
5   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
6   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.0   1.0
7   0.1   0.0   1.0   0.2   0.0   0.0
...
```

a_ and b_ represent gambles. The order of them is not necessary, so a_ might as well be b_.
I want to remove duplicates as in rows 1 and 2: The gamble pair in row 1 is the same as in row 2, only that gamble a and b have swapped places.

How do I filter my dataframe so that only one of these rows remains?

Desired output:

```
   a_p1  a_x1  a_x2  b_p1  b_x1  b_x2
1   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  -1.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
4   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
5   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.0   1.0
6   0.1   0.0   1.0   0.2   0.0   0.0
...
```

Comment: can `a_p1` be `b_x1`? and `a_p1` be `a_x1`?

Comment: No. 'a_p1' can be 'b_p1' if and only if 'a_x1' is 'b_x1' and 'a_x2' is 'b_x2'. Basically, there are two blocks: Columns starting with a_ and columns starting with b_. These are interchangable, however within a block there is no interchange possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea if all columns names are sorted - grouping by columns values after `_`, convert values to tuples, sorting and use `duplicated` for mask:

```
df1 = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
print (df1)
     a    a    a    b    b    b
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 -1.0  0.0
2  1.0 -1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
6  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0  1.0
7  0.1  0.0  1.0  0.2  0.0  0.0

print (df1.groupby(df1.columns, axis=1)
          .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), 1))
          .apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis=1))
1    ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, -1.0, 0.0))
2    ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, -1.0, 0.0))
3    ((0.0, -1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
4     ((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
5     ((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
6     ((0.1, 0.0, 0.0), (0.2, 0.0, 1.0))
7     ((0.1, 0.0, 1.0), (0.2, 0.0, 0.0))
dtype: object
```

---

```
m = (df1.groupby(df1.columns, axis=1)
         .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), 1))
         .apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis=1)
         .duplicated())

df2 = df[~m]
print (df2)
   a_p1  a_x1  a_x2  b_p1  b_x1  b_x2
1   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0  -1.0   0.0
3   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  -1.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
5   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
6   0.1   0.0   0.0   0.2   0.0   1.0
7   0.1   0.0   1.0   0.2   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also treat these rows as duplicates: 0.1  0  0  0.2  0  1, 0.1  0  1  0.2  0  0?

Comment: Let's assume I have the columns described in my comment. I think your code would treat them falsely as duplicates. No?

Comment: @MaxJ. - Answer was edited to original, nor removed only second row, last row not.